# Как в форме для обновления атрибутов объектов вложенной модели правильно передать параметры в radio_button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Есть несколько моделей задействованных в процессе, Trebute, вложенная в нее модель Trqa, и имеющая связь 1 к многим с моделью Trqa модель Answer. Код вьюхи:

```
    <h1>Trebutes#show</h1>
    <p>Find me in app/views/trebutes/show.html.erb</p>
    <%= form_for @trebute do |t| %>
    <table>
      <% @trebute.trqas.each do |q| %>
      <tr>
        <th colspan= '3'><%= q.question.question %></th>
      </tr>
      <%= t.fields_for q, q do |trs| %>
        <% i=0 %>
        <% q.question.answers.each do |a| %>
        <%#= trs.fields_for q do |tr| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= i += 1 %> </td>
        <td><%= a.answer %></td>
        <td><%= trs.radio_button(:answer_id, a.id) %></td>
      </tr>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <tr>
      <td colspan='3'><%= t.submit %></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <% end %>
```

В результате получаю такой `radio_button`:

```
<input id="trebute_trqa_answer_id_65" type="radio" name="trebute[trqa][answer_id]" value="65">
```

А должно быть что-то такое, как я понимаю:

```
<input id="trebute_trqa_trqa_id_answer_id_65" type="radio" name="trebute[trqa][answer_id]" value="65">
```

Comment: А что не так? Ну другой `id`, чем это вам мешает?